# Joomla (3.X) How to schedule a cron?

Tags: joomla, cron

> **Question : How to schedule a cron on Joomla ?

*Details : I've made a component, I want this component to execute once a day.*

Comment: Joomla is a CMS and a Framework. It does not have a built in cron scheduler. The best thing to do is to use your hosts scheduler. It's quite easy to write scripts for cron  jobs using the Joomla Framework. You seem like you want an application or component to schedule a job on your server rather than going to the control panel.  Because a CMS is only active when someone comes to the website you can't count on it to run cron jobs automatically, but what you can do is have triggers for your scripts that run whenever someone visits the site or logs in or whatever.

Comment: Actually the other thing you can do is write your own cron scheduler. If you have written a component already you can certainly write a small application that could do that.

Comment: try to do it with [cpanel](http://www.walkswithme.net/cron-jobs-setup-using-cpanel-in-linux-server)

Comment: Thank you guys for your advices. I posted the anwser below if you're interested.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how to build a cron with Joomla.

As Elin says, there is no cron builded in so we have to use the unix cron. The cron will call a php script. To make the script work you need to load Joomla framework.

You can get exemple in /cli

Here is my Cron

```
<?php

// Initialize Joomla framework
const _JEXEC = 1;

// Load system defines
if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php'))
{
    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__DIR__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

// Get the framework.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/import.legacy.php';

// Bootstrap the CMS libraries.
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/cms.php';

// Load the configuration
require_once JPATH_CONFIGURATION . '/configuration.php';

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

/**
 * Cron job 
 *
 */
class myCron extends JApplicationCli
{
    /**
     * Entry point for the script
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   2.5
     */
        public function doExecute()
        {

// YOUR CODE HERE
            require_once JPATH_BASE.'/administrator/components/com_mycom/helpers/XMLImporter.php';

            echo "CRON TASK START ";
        echo "\n"; // Use \n is you are executing the cron from the terminal.
       
            $instance = PropertyXMLImporter::instance();
            $instance->execute_import();

        echo "CRON TASK END ";
        echo "\n";
        }
    }

JApplicationCli::getInstance('myCron')->execute();
```

Now you need to schedule your cron.

Open the terminal and type

```
> crontab -e
```

If this opened as vi text editor you can press ZZ or :q! to exit then type this to get a better text editor (on mac)

```
> export EDITOR=nano
```

Then

```
> crontab -e
```

and add a line like this :

```
*/1 * * * * php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/YOURPROJECT/PATH-TO-THE-CRON/cronTask.php
```

You can check that this is ok by typing

```
> crontab -l
```

*/1 * * * * is Cron schedule syntax, check here to read about it : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

In our case I used */1 to trigger it every minitues to test purpose. Of course you want to change it when it's working. In my case I want it to run everyday at 3am. So I changed it for 0 3 * * *

IMPORTANT  1 : To launch a cron job every minute for test purpose don't forget the /1 ! ( */1 * * * * ) is not the same than (1 * * * *) .

IMPORTANT 2 : If you get this error while excecution your cron on localhost "Could not connect to MySQL." Change your configuration.php with

public $host = '127.0.0.1';

instead of  public $host = 'localhost';
Yes this one is a bi**h !
Lost a few hours on it ...

IMPORTANT 3 : The code I wrote above, is good if you put you cron in /cli. I'm not sure this is the best place, so remember to adapt the path to your cron location.

Stackoverflow is a huge help for me, I have benefited greatly from the anwsers of members, today I am very happy to participate to the community with this answer and I hope this will help developers like me that have no choice of working with Joomla.

I hope this can help someone !

Comment: Thanks for sharing Kaizoku, really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can Also cron set in cpanel and give cron file path on cpanel
give path this type :

/public_html/your_projects/cron.php

Comment: What if you don't have access to the Cpanel ?
Also the cpanel won't load the joomla class so it won't work